# Receving an error when trying to access my site with Opera mini: "could not locate remote server"

Tags: webserver, accessibility

I always receive an error when I try to access my [site](http://www.akses-stan.com) via Opera mini on Android (version: 7.5 build: 33361): `could not locate remote server`

I've used another browser on the same device and it can be opened without this error.

My site is built on WordPress using the Bootstrap theme. I've tried switching to another theme and disabling plugins, but it still doesn't work.

Is there something I can try to fix this?

Comment: You might try asking this question on Opera's [forums](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/tgr.dml?id=4).

Comment: Yup, I've seen the forum and following post which has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia's article on Opera Mini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini):

> By default, Opera Mini opens one connection to the proxy servers, which it keeps open and re-uses as required. This improves transfer speed and enables the servers to quickly synchronize changes to bookmarks

This means that if there is a problem with the proxy server used by Opera Mini, your site will not be accessible, even if the site itself is up.

Comment: i pulled it up on iphone, same result. pull up google.com, it loads. its not the proxy

Comment: I think this is the network or proxy issue in Opera, I've try opening the site today and finally it opened without error.

Thanks all for your help